# Custom post types displaying all category posts instead of showing posts only from specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am having issues with custom post type categories display.
I have created custom post type for review site
I want to show different categories in different tabs
but when I put any category of review in menu it shows all reviews
instead of showing reviews from specific category
For example:
I have created 2 categories in reviews
a) Games 
b) software
Whenever I choose Games category it shows posts from software category too.

I had same issue with blog posts categories but I resolved that issue using code
in my category.php file

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
         $cat_id = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title(null, false) );
                 query_posts(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'cat'=>$cat_id,

        ));
```

I have created taxonomy.php file for custom post type

```
<?php $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'cpreviews','paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
```

Can anyone please help us to understand what we need to do to display posts
according to categories for custom post types?

UPDATED CODE IN TAXONOMY.PHP but still have some issue:

I have changed above code under taxonomy.php to

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
          //$currentTerm = $_GET[ 'term' ]; 
          $cat_id = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title(null, false) );
          $mypost = array('post_type' => 'cptreviews',
                      'paged' => $paged,
                      'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_reviews_product_category',
                                'terms' => (''),
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'name' =>'Product Category',
                                )
                            )
                        );
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
```

Now whenever I put category in 'terms' => ('kids') like this it shows all posts under that category only. but I want to take that 'terms value' dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by creating taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php file & removed tax query code..it automatically takes given category..thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$type = 'cpreviews';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal for your help but its showing all posts under that cpreviews post type irrespective of categories again. I need to show different categories. Is there any option that we can call custom post type categories like I did in category.php?

Comment: what do u want..? exactly... categories or posts of particular category.../?

Comment: Posts of particular categories. I want to create different menus for different categories so it will display related posts under those categories. Right now all posts are displaying under every category.

Comment: Have you tried the above answer. Thats showing the posts from particular category. Whats your categories name? Are these default wordpress categories or you created custom taxonomy?

Comment: Yes, I have tried above answer. Its showing all the posts in every category. I have 2 files for blog, I am using default category.php which is working great & for custom post types(reviews) I am using taxonomy.php but its showing all the posts . hence I changed code, which you can see under Changed code under my question. whenever I put categories in 'terms' => ('') its showing posts for that exact category. Say if I have category Kids & put 'terms' => ('kids') it shows all posts from kids only. but as it is theme I want code to take that(category) value dynamically...how can we do that?

Comment: if category slug is appearing in url you can use $_REQUEST to get the slug and use slug to get category name.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have Custom Post Type: cpReviews --- Custom Taxonomy: RevCategories --- Create new review post and chose category from RevCategories. Query cpReviews will definitely show all the posts, you need to do some thing like this -----

```
query_posts(array(
        'post_type' =>'cpreviews', //Custom_Post_TYpe
        'showposts' => $limit,  
        'RevCategories' => 'Games',));  //Custom Post Type TAxonomy (can use page name here get_query_var('pagename'); for dynamic content
while (have_posts()): the_post(); global $post; echo the_title(); endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve this issue.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'cat' => 'Games'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```